# Check if an argument is present and set a value accordingly

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a program in Python that requires checking if an argument is present and then set a value to be used in the program accordingly. For example:

`abc -a -b`

Both `-a` and `-b` are optional. But `-a` provides a default value of some port number (say port 1234) to the program. But if `-b` is present, then the program must default to a different port number (say 2215).

How can I do this with `argparse`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a',
                    action='store_const',
                    const=1234,
                    dest='port')

parser.add_argument('-b',
                    action='store_true',
                    dest='port_override')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.port_override:
    args.port = 2215

print(args.port)
```

This tells `argparse` that if `-a` is specified, then the value `1234` will be stored in `args.port`. Also, if `-b` is specified, then `args.port_override` will be `True`. After performing argument parsing, we can check the value of `args.port_override`.

You could do this, too:

```
parser.add_argument('-b',
                    action='store_const',
                    const=2215
                    dest='port')
```

In this case, whichever comes second will override the other.